# Embedding clickable flowchart in kentico 10 website

Tags: kentico, flowchart

Currently our content editors creates a flowchart in visio - and now we're trying to figure out the best way of allowing them to embed that in a kentico website.

We get them currently to export and add as a media library image which doesn't allow the content editor to hyperlink items in the flowchart to pages which could have more information.

Some other options we have considered:

- exporting visio flowchart to pdf and displaying that pdf in the browser instead of the image.
- third party tool that would host the flowchart content which we then embed into the kentico website using an iframe.
- visio exporting the flowchart as html - but that includes a folder and various files which seems painful to integrate with our kentico website.

Just wondering if anyone else has any recommended approaches that we might not be considering?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially there are many ways to solve this issue. You can [go with a classic way (image with set of areas defined)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33551367/link-different-parts-of-an-image-to-different-urls)

Use some online tools like http://www.image-maps.com/ to create an image map. You can use static text web part and paste your html there:

```
<img alt="someImage" src="~/Images/someimage.jpg" usemap="#ImageMap" />
<map name="ImageMap" id="ImageMap">
<area shape="rect" coords="727,25,907,89" href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank" alt="Your Alt Text Here..." />
<area shape="rect" coords="309,25,646,98" href="home.aspx" alt="Your Alt Text Here..." />
</map>
```

You can even clone for example editable image web part, adjust its properties to your needs (i.e. to area map property), but you still have to use outside tools to create an image map.

Comment: That tool looks a little rough - but a tool to generate an image map is a helpful suggestion thanks!